# OWIN Startup class not auto-detected despite having Startup.cs in matching assembly name and global assembly name

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created a [web API](https://github.com/saraford/My-Web-API-2) and added the OWIN middleware to the project, i.e. Startup.cs, the Startup.Auth.cs, and OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider.cs (as needed for Azure AD B2C).

However, my Web API requires that I use the assembly attribute `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(My_Web_API_2.Startup))]` in Startup.cs, otherwise the OWIN startup class isn't detected. The [TaskService app in the Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/Startup.cs) doesn't require the attribute to work.

The [OWIN Startup class detection docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) state that

> Naming Convention: Katana looks for a class named Startup in
>   namespace matching the assembly name or the global namespace.

But my web API is using a matching assembly name and global namespace? What am I missing from my web API to detect the OWIN Startup class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly name has `-`'s but the namespace has `_`'s.

[image: assembly and namespace names]

This probably happened when you performed a `File -> New Project`.  VS converted the hyphens to underscores in the namespace for you (and didn't tell you!).